# Python Numpy Unwrap function does not work as intended

Tags: python, ads, degrees, phase, unwrap

I went through an ordeal with numpy.unwrap() function and came to realize it does not work as intended. Comparing the function to ADS unwrap function proved this. I'm sure it works when working with radians. But when working in degrees, it does not. Even when passing a discount with a conversion to degrees, it's output is no where correct. So be aware of this if you are using this function intended with degrees. I am currently seeking a solution.

Comment: 1. Does not specify what "the unwrap function" is or does or where it comes from. 2. Does not ask a question. (This could be addressed by posting the answer as an answer; [it's OK to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).) 3. The function provided isn't actually a function.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I went ahead and made those changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better solution for an unwrap function.
I had a go at writing my own function for unwrapping a column in a dataframe. Work perfectly. So anyone encountering this issue in the future will hopefully find this solution.

```
def myUnwrapFunc(unwrapTempDF, phase) # Data must be in degrees
    prevRow = unwrapTempDF[phase].iat[0]
    for rowIndex, row in enumerate(unwrapTempDF[phase]):
        if abs(row - prevRow) > 180:
            if row - prevRow < 0:
                unwrapTempDF[phase].iat[rowIndex] = row + 360
                row = row + 360
            else: 
                unwrapTempDF[phase].iat[rowIndex] = row - 360
                row = row - 360
         prevRow = unwrapTempDF[phase].iat[rowIndex]
```